# Building custom tooltip with hyperlink using QGIS

Tags: qgis, maptips

I am working on a project for publishing old scanned maps in jpeg at the scale of 1: 500e and converted into pdf. The goal of the project is to digitize the polygons representing the street small islands associated with the maps in order to geolocate them via a hyperlink from a tooltip when the user moves with the mouse cursor in the map canvas with QGIS.

The PDF files of the maps are located in a remote directory of our server and I would like to be able to create a tooltip in which I can display the attribute informations of polygon layers as well as the hyperlink that allows me to display the corresponding plan to my zone (location of the polygons of the small islands).

How could I achieve this in a simple way in QGIS?

All your suggestions and comments are welcome!

Comment: It is called "Map Tips" (or Map tip, Maptip) in QGIS. Information [before QGIS 2.16](https://nathanw.net/2012/08/05/html-map-tips-in-qgis/) and  [QGIS 2.16 or later](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog216/index.html#feature-map-tip-improvements) may be of use.

Comment: Hi Kazuhito,I didn't pay pay attention to this features implemented in the version 2.16. Sounds good, so I'll try it  and see if things work well. Regards

Comment: Yes, Seems it is getting even more powerful tool. Unfortunately I cannot find many use cases yet. If you can post your result as your answer (or whatever way you feel comfortable), it would be great!

Comment: Hi Kazuhito,I don't have a chance to test it yet. But next e=week, I would be good to test it and give you any feed-back. Regards!

Answer (score 1):

The function to show information at tooltip is called `Map Tips` (or `Map tip`, `Maptip`) in QGIS.

Basic usage is:

(1) Set a text / html in the `Layer Properties | Display` option.

(2) Click on **Map Tips** [image] icon to activate.

Syntax to write the Map Tips can differ according to QGIS version.